# Good xml and csv import module with GUI

Tags: import, xml, csv

Does anybody know a good import module for csv?

I want an easy GUI import for remote images or/and sheets. Also I need a mapping function.

For wordpress I once used : www.wpallimport.com  wich I totally loved! Is there something similair for Magento?

gr

Answer (score 1):

You can use either Magento's [dataflow](https://www.labworkz.com/tutorial-magento-importexport-dataflow-profiles/) or check out [Magmi](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). Those to have the most advance GUI interface.

Optionally there is a paid service like [Cobby](http://www.cobby.io/) you can use if you like a nicer GUI

Comment: Never heard of Cobby, but interesting. Have you used it @Sander?

Comment: Nope, but I know one of the devs and he's pretty good :)